# Not Receiving OTP from FireBase from second Time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

I am trying to receive OTP number from Firebase using Android App. I am getting OTP every time after phone restarts and after that I am not getting any OTP. Any help is highly appreciated. My project contains below four activities.

**Options Tried to resolve this issue**

1. Cleared the Data on the phone. Its same issue for other users too.

Answer (score 2):

You should first remove

```
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

Shouldn't be called 5 times in a row. Just do it once and in **onStop** method:

```
override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
}
```

I think you should then set

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

only **once** and be sure to put this preferably in your **custom Application** class:

```
class CustomApplication : Application() {
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    /**
     * Firebase Initialization code
     * **/

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)
}}
```

Then, in your Manifest.xml file:

```
<application
        android:name=".CustomApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

....
....

```
</application>
```

**Official Firebase github Repo**

In addition, be sure to check out the example code for **Firebase/quickstart-android - PhoneAuthActivity** for phone authentication of the official repository:
[quickstart-android for phone authentication](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/kotlin/PhoneAuthActivity.kt)

You should then be ready to go with proper phone authentication implementation with Firebase.

Comment: Thanks for your comment bu I tried this solution but it didn't help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Step:1 I have removed all the multiple signout and included onStop() method.  Step:2 I have included intializeApp method Step:3 I have changed my manifest file

Comment: @Josh Steps you should consider in order to solve your issue: *1)* Move FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this) to CustomApplication class. *2)* Add CustomApplication class name in Manifest. *3)* In MainActivity, remove FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut() from onCreate and put it eventually in onStop. *4)* In order to get the phonenumber (after successfully OTP), put back intent.putExtra("phonenumber", phonenumber) when task.isSuccessful(). *5)* Change (reorder) the logic of your Logout to SignOut from FirebaseAuth only when LogOut Button is clicked

Comment: What kind of action does CustomApplication perform? I am not sure about EmojiManage and MapBox

Comment: When every Android Application run, the class Application is launched first. You can override this class (the name CustomApplication is arbitrary, you can choose any name you want). When you override Application class, you can do additional initialization. The code I put first **was an example** of the initialization of multiple libraries. In your case, just put `class CustomApplication : Application() {
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    /**
     * Firebase Initialization code
     * **/

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)
}}`

Comment: Where do you want me to add override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
} method. Below on start or any specification for this one.

Comment: Please check again [Quick start Android - PhoneAuthActivity](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/kotlin/PhoneAuthActivity.kt). In the official repository example, everything is in the same Activity and signOut is called *ONLY* when the signOut Button is clicked. To keep things simple, don't use `override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
}` for now and check above steps again.

Comment: I tried above steps and still it didn't work for me.